# Java how to know the type of object has been created

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes that inherit from another class

```
class AEntity {
    private String name;
    public AEntity(String name){this.name = name;}
}

class Course extends AEntity {
    private String code;
    public Course(String name, String code){
        super(name);
        this.code = code;
    }
}

class Classroom extends AEntity {
    private String code;
    public Classroom(String name, String code){
        super(name);
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Now, there is a "middle" class that I want to take notice of the type of AEntity has been created. Different classes can create different types of AEntity.

```
class AEntityDefinition {
    private AEntity entity;
    public void setEntity(AEntity ae){this.entity = ae;}
    public AEntity getEntity(){return this.entity;}
}
```

Now, I have a class that creates an instance of AEntity class and therefore I use `AEntityDefinition` class.

```
class C1 {
    private AEntityDefinition aEntityDefinition;
    public C1(){
        aEntityDefinition = new AEntityDefinition();
        aEntityDefinition.setEntity(new Course("Course","Course code"));
    }
}
```

Finally, I want to call `getEntity()` in order to see the type of AEntity that has been created.

```
public class EntityDefinition {
    public static void main(String[] dgf){
        AEntityDefinition aEntityDefinition = new AEntityDefinition();
        System.out.println(aEntityDefinition.getEntity() instanceof Course);
        System.out.println(aEntityDefinition.getEntity());
    }
}
```

Running the project returns null, because `entity` variable is not known outside class. My question is: How am I going to get the type of AEntity inside main, without passing from C1? Is there any way to do that, or there is another approach? Thank you in advance.

### Context:

I have some client code that creates and stores an AEntity within an AEntityDefinition that is a field inside another (unspecified) class. I would like to be able to solve this without changing the code for the client class too much, or preferably not at all, because there are numerous classes that could be containers.

Comment: Do you want to know the class of the entity in the definition in the instance of C1 from outside the instance?

Comment: You get null as your main class doesn't access C1 in any way. It only creates a AEntityDefinition without a Entity inside it.

Comment: `null` is the correct value!

Comment: haha naturally the correct value is null! But how am I supposed to know the class of the entity instead, like @Bohemian said?

Comment: You can't get that without having a object of the class. I think you got something wrong with OOP, so maybe you might want to take a look at a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a getter:

```
class C1 {
    private AEntityDefinition aEntityDefinition;
    public C1(){
        aEntityDefinition = new AEntityDefinition();
        aEntityDefinition.setEntity(new Course("Course","Course code"));
    }

    public Class<? extends AEntity> getEntityType() {
        return aEntityDefinition.getEntity().getClass();
    }
}
```

You may want to put some null checking in there in case the entity definition or the entity can be null.

---

If you can't change class C1, but you know that it has an `AEntityDefinition` field and you want to get a reference to the AEntity instance inside it, use can use reflection:

```
public static Class<? extends AEntity> getEntityType(Object o) throws Exception {
    for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (AEntityDefinition.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            AEntityDefinition def = (AEntityDefinition) field.get(o);
            return def.getEntity().getClass();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Should I put this in every class that create some type of AEntity, or could I add it somewhere else with "global" access instead? I don't want to use C1 object for any reason

Comment: What is the purpose of C1? Can you eliminate it if you don't want to use it? If you can't eliminate it and you can't change it, you could use reflection to examine its field of type `AEntityDefinition` and delve it to find the class of its value - does that sound appealing?

Comment: Think of C1 as a button handler (AddButtonHandler, EditButtonHandler etc). I use chain of responsibility design pattern for all buttons. I want to open a specific window for every type of AEntity. The problem is, I don't know which type of entity has been chosen from menu. Could you please explain to me your idea? How could I use reflection etc?

Comment: See edit to answer showing how to use reflection to get the class inside the definition that is a field of the object. Add null checking as you wish.

Comment: you lost me here...I use reflection inside C1, although I don't have access to it? How would I call in main?

Comment: That method has nothing to do with class C1. It's a static method you can call from anywhere and pass in anything. Call that method from main passing the instance of C1 (or any class at all). If there's a AEntityDefinition field inside the object passed to it, that method will return the class of its entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63711/discussion-between-vassilis-de-and-bohemian).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a simple `getClass` call?

```
AEntity ae = aEntityDefinition.getEntity();
String klass = ae != null ? ae.getClass().getName() : "*not defined*";
System.out.println("The class type is " + klass);
```

Comment: adding it in main, I get `defined`. Unfortunatelly it doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: You get `defined`? where does that come from?

Comment: sorry...`not defined`

Comment: Okay, that is obvious ... because you've never used the `setEntity` method at that point in time. You mentioned that you don't want to pass C1, you won't be able to get around that ... you "need" a reference to the internal AEntityDefinition object.